# Calculating Sales Percentage with Jquery

Tags: jquery, math, jquery-calculation

I have to calculate sales percentage between two variables and I was wondering how to do that with jQuery.

I would use the following formula to get my sales percentage

```
(40-30)/40 * 100 = 25%.
```

Inputting my parseFloated variables would look like the following

```
(tiLine - tiSale) / tiLine * 100 = fixedTo [1]('%')
```

What is the proper syntax for an equation like this?

Comment: @MattD there is nothing wrong with this question for someone who doesn't know JS syntax. They have showed an attempt at some formula to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @Adjit But OP has already figured out the syntax.  The left hand side of the equations are valid js.  So when they get to the last line of the question, the only thing I can think is "what in the world are you trying to ask?"  The fact that I have to compare the (pseudo-accepted) answer with the question to decide that maybe they're trying to figure out the syntax for `toFixed` means that they should have been clearer in their original question.

Comment: @Teepeemm What? as the OP stated they wanted to know how to write a formula in jQuery and what the proper syntax of the provided formula/pseudo code would be. There is no reason for you to have to compare the answer to the question if you read the question. Besides, that is also what the comments are for, if you are unclear than ask - are you trying to figure out the syntax for `toFixed`? before discrediting a question that doesn't make complete sense to you try understanding it or asking the OP to be clearer instead of saying 'we're not here to do your work' as that is not constructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery syntax follows the same syntax as JavaScript. jQuery is basically JavaScript on steroids. So for the most part you have the answer already. Just create a helper function to take get the sales percentage.

Your syntax would have to go something like this:

```
function salesPcnt(tiLine, tiSale) {
   var pcnt = ((tiLine - tiSale)/tiLine) * 100;
   return pcnt.toFixed[2] + '%';
}
```

What this function does is returns the percentage in string form. So now, all you would need to do is call the function and use the return value properly.

ie. Usage for jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tiLine = 40;
   var tiSale = 30;
   console.log(salesPcnt(tiLine, siSale));  //will print 25.00%
});
```